# K&R C Book: Question on Malloc implementation p187

Tags: c

Can anyone explain why the following statement on Page 187 of Edition 2 for malloc implementation is used:

```
nunits = (nbytes+sizeof(Header)-1)/sizeof(Header)+1;
```

[p187 Malloc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZMjp.png)

Specifically, why the offsets -1 and +1 are used to calculate nunits.

Comment: When you see something like this and don't understand it, it's often useful to write out some sample inputs and results (as one of the answers shows). It's a good way to develop some initial intuition about what type of thing the code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(n-1)/d + 1` calculates `n` divided by `d` with any non-zero fraction rounded up.

In C, with positive integer operands, `n/d` calculates `n` divided by `d` with rounding down. If we compute `(n-1)/d + 1`, then:

- If there is any fraction in `n/d`, then `(n-1)/d` has the same value as `n/d`, so `(n-1)/d + 1` is one greater, so it is the result of rounding up a fraction when dividing `n` by `d`.
- If there is no fraction in `n/d`, then `(n-1)/d` is one less than `n/d`, so `(n-1)/d + 1` is the same as `n/d`, so it is the desired result of calculating `n/d` when there is no fraction.

This is the desired function to calculate for the number of units needed because, if you need a space for a fraction of a unit, then you need a whole unit to keep that fraction in.

Comment: This is clever!  I see how it works, is this a theorem in mathematics?

Comment: @notaorb: Given it relies on the truncating behavior of division in C, it's kind of tangential to what mathematicians are typically concerned with. But it's fairly obvious from simply examining the two meaningful cases, no special theorem needed.

Answer (score 2):

It rounds up the size of the allocation requested to the next unit of `sizeof(Header)` and divides by `sizeof(Header)` to give the number of units of headers needed to store the data requested, and adds one to give it a header to use for the control information that will be wrecked when you write outside the bounds of the allocated memory.

If the header size is 16 bytes, for example, then the request sizes produce:

```
 1..16   2
17..32   3
33..48   4
```

Etc.